# Contains<T>() and how to implement it

Tags: c#, linq

Say a class

```
Person  
+Name: string  
+Contacts: List<Person>
```

I want to be able to check if a person has a contact with a certain name without having to create a dummy Person instance.

```
person.Contacts.Contains<string>("aPersonName");
```

This should check all persons in the Contacts list if their Name.Equals("aPersonName");
I see that there is a Contains already available, but I don't know where I should implement it's logic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's probably easiest to use [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
 return person.Contacts.Any(person => person.Name=="aPersonName");
```

Alternatively, project and then contain:

```
 return person.Select(person => person.Name).Contains("aPersonName");
```

Comment: It's indeed the easiest. Although I would really have liked the person.Contacts.Contains("aPerson"); Just because that would give me the opportunity to put the comparing code at a central place.

Comment: Putting the code in an extension method like I suggested in a different question would enable the person.Contacts.Contains("aPerson") syntax.

Comment: I'd write a slightly different extension method, personally, to allow person.Contacts.Contains(p => p.Name, "aPerson"). That makes it really obvious what's going on. It's on my list for "enhanced LINQ to objects"...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the Contacts is the Contacts for the person in question (person in your code snippit)

List has a contains method that takes an object of type T as a parameter and returns true or false if that object exists in the list. What your wanting is IList.Exists method,  Which takes a predicate.

example (c# 3.0)

```
bool hasContact = person.Contacts.Exists(p => p.Name == "aPersonName");
```

or (c# 2.0)

```
bool hasContact = person.Contacts.Exists(delegate(Person p){ return p.Name == "aPersonName"; });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Jon's `Any`, but if you are stuck with C# 2.0, or C# 3.0 with .NET 2.0/3.0 and no LINQBridge, then another approach is `List<T>.Find` or `List<T>.Exists`. I'll illustrate with `Find`, since `Exists` got posted just as I was about to hit the button ;-p

```
// C# 2.0
bool knowsFred = person.Contacts.Find(delegate(Person x) { return x.Name == "Fred"; }) != null;
// C# 3.0
bool knowsFred = person.Contacts.Find(x => x.Name == "Fred") != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the extension method

```
public static bool Contains(this IList<Person> list, string name) {
    return list.Any(c => c.Name == name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions already presented by Jon Skeet and yapiskan are the way to go.  If you need exactly what you're stating then you could write an extension method:

```
public static class ContactListExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains<T>(this List<Person> contacts, string aPersonName)
    {
        //Then use any of the already suggested solutions like:
        return contacts.Contains(c => c.Name == aPersonName);
    }
}
```